# For loops with sheet range in declaration

Tags: excel, vba

So I was making a For loop that would fill values in cells on Sheet1. Its upperbound was a row number on Sheet2, and I figured that would be slower than saving the row number to a variable. In case this isn't entirely clear, what I'm saying is that my intuition told me

```
For i = 1 to Sheet2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
```

would obviously be slower than

```
For i = 1 to lastRow
```

since the For loop would have to keep referencing Sheet2. I then remembered that every time I debug a For loop and put a breakpoint at the declaration* statement, it would never stop at that line. So I figured then that they'd at least be the same amount of time since maybe they both just get temporarily saved. I made a quick test before asking this and to my surprise, the Sheet-referencing loop was actually slightly faster than the other.

Does anyone know why this could be?

*what is this line actually called? declaration of a For loop? Conditional statement?

Comment: The end is set the first time, and cannot be reset as it never recalculates, so no, there should not be a noticeable difference.

Comment: to piggy back off the other comments, it *may* be slower if you were doing a `Do While`/`Until` loop. AFAIK that condition is checked each loop, unlike `For` loops`

Comment: The single calculation of the start / end values is also why a breakpoint on the `For` line only stops the code once - it is only ever reached once.

Comment: I agree with both of you in that there shouldn't be a noticeable difference in time and that it could be slower if I changed the actual loop. But there is a .3 second difference over 100000 lines when I tested it, which I've done about 20 times now! So not noticeable, sure, but still interesting to me

Comment: My guess would be that as commented above, your for loop parameters are only being evaluated once.  In the top example, it just evaluates the row.  The second one has an additional variable declared, still has to do the same row evaluation, and then also has to assign this to the variable and evaluate the variable.